# Why str_trim of a matrix returns a vector?

Tags: regex, r

In order to deal with trailing/leading spaces, I found out this function `str_trim`. When applied to a matrix of strings, it return a vector. I am confused.

```
library(stringr)
str_trim(matrix("   strings     ",3,3))
```

In fact, I usually use `gsub`, and when applied to a matrix, gsub return a matrix, which is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `?stringr::str_trim()` the output is expected to be a vector:

> Value:
>
> A character vector.

One possibility to obtain the desired output consists in using the base R function `trimws()`:

```
trimws(matrix("   strings     ",3,3))
#     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
#[1,] "strings" "strings" "strings"
#[2,] "strings" "strings" "strings"
#[3,] "strings" "strings" "strings"
```

Answer (score 4):

`str_trim` simply always returns a dimensionless vector. However, you can preserve the matrix shape by doing a structured assignment:

```
mat = matrix("   strings     ",3,3)
mat[] = str_trim(mat)
```

Comment: Wow, this is very interesting ! structured assignment. How does this work exactly ? I noticed that if I do : m[]=str_trim(mat), it doesn't work. So in a structured assignment, you have to have the same variable name ? In what other circumstances it can also work ?

Comment: @KilianS No, the same variable name isn’t necessary, the replacement data just has to have the same vector length — in your case 9. For instance, the following would also work: `mat[] = letters[1 : 9]`. The code you tried will also work if `mat` and `m` have the same number of elements.